# Event target's name is undefined if not an input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, contenteditable

I have this component:

```
...

onInputChange = evt => {
  const target = evt.target;
  let value = null;
  if (target.nodeName === "INPUT")
    value = target.value; //works well
  else if (target.nodeName === "SPAN")
    value = target.innerText; //works well
  const name = target.name; //works well if it's the input, doesn't if it's the span
  this.setState({[name]: value});
}

render() {
  ...
  <input name="myFirstValue" onChange={onInputChange} />
  <span name="mySecondValue" contentEditable="true" onInput={onInputChange}></span>
  ...
}

...
```

When it's the `input` that triggers the event, it works well. But the problem is when it's the `span`: `target.name` returns `undefined` and not `'mySecondValue'`.

Is this a bug from React? If so, is there a workaround?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put a "name" attribute on any element you want, but only `<form>` "interactive" elements have DOM APIs that allow you to treat it as a gettable/settable property on the DOM node. Otherwise, you have to use `.getAttribute()` and `.setAttribute()` (which should work for `<input>` etc too).

Thus

```
const name = target.getAttribute("name");
```

or maybe

```
const name = target.name || target.getAttribute("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

`event.target.name` works when the event is fired on any element that has a name attribute.

```
<input
type="text"
id="nume"
**name="lastName"**
class="form-control"
placeholder="Nume"
required
autoFocus
defaultValue={employeeData.lastName || ""}
onChange={handleChange}
/>
```